# Silverlight not printing from all browsers

Tags: silverlight, browser, printing

Yesterday I created a print function in our Silverlight 4 application and thought all was fine. Today though our tester was not able to print using it from his IE8 browser. When he prints from IE8 the Windows print dialog displays but when he clicks its print button the dialog closes and nothing is sent to the printer. He also has Firefox installed and the print works fine when he prints from there. He is also able to print other pages from IE8 using it's normal print function. I have no problem printing from either IE9 or Chrome.

So there is clearly some problem with his IE8 installation. Any ideas on how to track this down and fix it would be appreciated.

The ChildWindow I'm printing from contains the following XAML

```
<Border x:Name="PrintRange" BorderBrush="#00000000" BorderThickness="10">
  <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="White" CornerRadius="5">
    <Grid Margin="10">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <Image Source="/MiX.DLD.Web.UI.Silverlight;component/Images/VdoLogo.png" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0" />
      <TextBlock Text="DLD" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                 Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
      <TextBlock Text="IMPORTANT NUMBERS" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,5,0,5" 
                 Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
      <TextBlock Text="IMEI NUMBER" FontSize="12" Grid.Row="2" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding ImeiNumber,Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
      <TextBlock Text="SERIAL NUMBER" FontSize="12" Grid.Row="3" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding SerialNumber,Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" />
      <TextBlock Text="REGISTRATION CODE" FontSize="12" Grid.Row="4" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding RegistrationCode,Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
  </Border>
</Border>
```

and I print with the following code

```
var pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.PrintPage += (s, args) => { args.PageVisual = PrintRange; };
pd.Print("MiX DLD pre-registration label");
```